# H2o autoencoder anomaly detection for multivariate time series data

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

I am applying H2o autoencoder for anomaly detection for multivariate time series data.

I have many time series data for different metrics of network elements which are recorded every 15 minutes. I want to find out that:

1. At which timestamp that the anomaly happens
2. What is/are the main metric(s) causing the anomaly

I form the data matrix with columns as metrics and rows as the values of the metrics at a specific timestamp. For example, [[9:15, v1, v2, v3...], [9:30, v4, v5, v6, ...], ...].

I then train the data with autoencoder and use h2o.anomaly to check which data points have reconstruction MSE greater than the 99% percentile as the suspected anomalies. And these give me the timestamp when the possible anomalies happen.

By using this method, can I get the information of the main metrics causing the anomaly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get solution to the problem using H2o or thru different means?

Comment: I turn back to apply H2o autoencoder for univariate time series data. It works for me, even through it takes time to run for each individual time series data.